# Geometries are exported wrongly from PostGIS to Mapbox

Tags: geojson, mapbox, json

I am trying to export some features for UK from PostGIS to Mapbox, in PostGIS seems that geometries and everything is correct but when I upload the layer to Mapbox it appear with weird geometries.

When opening the .json in QGIS features and geometries are correct, also in PostGIS when I preview the data.

Problem is probably with Tippecanoe to generate the mbtiles. I have also tried to import to Mapbox directly as it is not very large json but I get the message of invalid CSV or GeoJSON. I have also tried exporting as shapefiles but still same result.
coordinate is 4326 for mapbox and 27700 for the layer. I have transformed them `ST_Transform(geom,4326)` so it doesn't throw same error for other layers, it is just for this one.

```
tippecanoe --read-parallel -o value_data.mbtiles --minimum-zoom=13 --maximum-zoom=16 -l value_data path/to/value_data.json
```

[image: Those are the geometries I got the details are correct and these are the geometries which appear in Mapbox]

Comment: In what coordinate system is the shapefile? And the map service? Please [edit] the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to redo the mbtile? it seems that the file where you are reading to run the tippecanoe is correpted or oversimplifiying the polygons. Try to force the SRID and build. Add some parameters like is in the samples in the git repo for tippecanoe like -b13 -r13...

Answer (score 0):

Saw a similar issue mentioned in other request - [Mapbox GL JS: Displaying polygons from different coordinate systems / projections](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368332/mapbox-gl-js-displaying-polygons-from-different-coordinate-systems-projection)

Please refer and see if this fix your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).